# Do i need a canadian visa for a connecting flight to bogota colombia?

Tags: visas

I have a Venezuelan passport. I am flying from US to Bogota, Colombia and will be changing flights in Toronto. I will not be leaving the airport and my layover in Toronto is for 2 hours. I have a L1 visa for the US. My passport is from Venezuela. Airline: Air Canada. Thank you.